# Can't Upload More Than One File at a Time in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I post to the following controller action:

```
<EmployeeAuthorize()>
<HttpPost()>
Function SendNewMessage(ByVal files1 As HttpPostedFileBase, ByVal files2 As HttpPostedFileBase) As JsonResult

    Debug.Print("files1=" + files1.ToString)
    Debug.Print("files2=" + files2.ToString)



    Dim result = New Dictionary(Of String, String)




    Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(files1.FileName)
    Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName)

    files1.SaveAs(filePath)


    Dim fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(files2.FileName)
    Dim filePath2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName)

    files2.SaveAs(filePath)




    Return Json(result)

End Function
```

I get an error on the `Debug.Print("files2=" + files2.ToString)` line that says, "`NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`"

This is the view I am using:

```
        @Using Html.BeginForm("SendNewMessage", "Message", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "sendForm", .enctype="multipart/form-data"})

            @<div class="sendBox">


                <h2 style="margin: 10px 0 0 0;">Attachments:</h2>
                <label>Attachment 1: &nbsp;<input type="file" name="files1" id="file1" class="files"/></label>
                <label>Attachment 2: &nbsp;<input type="file" name="files2" id="file2" class="files"/></label>
                <label>Attachment 3: &nbsp;<input type="file" name="files3" id="file3" class="files"/></label>

                <input type="submit" value="Send" />

        </div>

        End Using
```

The first file is fine (`files1`).  Why can't I upload more than one file?

Comment: have you put a break point and looked to make sure that `.Files` has more then one?

Comment: I haven't tried that.  I am not familiar with the practice of using breakpoints (though I know it's quite basic)...

Comment: put the cursor in the line `For Each i In Request.Files` (or w/e it is now) and press `F9` then press `F5` That will put your program in debug mode. Try upload your files. Once your code hits that point it will stop. You can then examine `.Files`

Comment: So you have removed all javascript and AJAX from your code? Also could you please remove all the noise such as `resources`, `subject` and `message` from your code and leave only the strict minimum? Is it still not working after you remove all the markup and leave only the 3 file input fields inside the form? It is really important to remove all the javascript and other noise so that you are able to more easily isolate the problem.

Comment: Removing all the noise almost works in that I no longer receive the null reference exception.  Only the first file uploads, still `files2` doesn't get uploaded.  I will post my current code.

Comment: @user1477388, all javascript disabled? All references to `jquery.form.js` removed?

Comment: Yes.  It now just goes to a blank page with JSON output.  There are no errors, it outputs `files1=System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper
files2=System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper` but only uploads one of the files (`files1`).

Comment: But that's because you have used the `filename` variable twice instead of using `filename2` for the second `SaveAs`. Same remark about the `filePath` variable. You are just saving the same file twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using the same `fileName` variable twice. Same stands true for the `filePath` variable that you are using twice. So replace:

```
Dim fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(files2.FileName)
Dim filePath2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName)
files2.SaveAs(filePath)
```

with:

```
Dim fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(files2.FileName)
Dim filePath2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName2)
files2.SaveAs(filePath2)
```

Comment: Great work, I didn't spot that.  Now I have to go back and figure out what else might have been breaking it as I add the other parameters to the method header.

Comment: The main issue was this:  In my dropdown list notice how I called `@Html.DropDownList("Resources",` but in my function header I call `Function SendNewMessage(ByVal Resource As Integer,`.  I needed to add `Function SendNewMessage(ByVal Resources As Integer,` and it would have worked, probably!